# SinonJS spy call seems not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, spy

I'm trying to spy a method call from a class instance, like this:

```
export class MyClass {
  async method(project, service) {
    console.log('calling my method');
  }
}
```

and then on my test, I'm doing like this:

```
const classInstance = new MyClass();
const spy = sandbox.spy(classInstance, 'method');
classInstance.method();
sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
```

The weird thing is, the "console.log" is printed out, but the sinon assertion is saying that the method is not called :\

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. I am using `"sinon": "^8.1.1"`. E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyClass {
  async method(project, service) {
    console.log('calling my method');
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('60605728', () => {
  it('should spy', () => {
    const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    const classInstance = new MyClass();
    const spy = sandbox.spy(classInstance, 'method');
    classInstance.method('project', 'service');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
  60605728
calling my method
    ✓ should spy


  1 passing (10ms)
```